# Firebase Database stopped working on Android Oreo after upgrading from version 11.0.4 to 15.0.1. Is there a way to reset Firebase "cache"?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, upgrade

So, we rolled out a new version of our app and we included an upgraded version of Firebase in the dependencies.

Some people who are using Android Oreo and upgraded the app are reporting the fact that those parts of the app that use Firebase Database are not working.

The only Error lines that we see in the log are like these:

```
05-14 11:45:55.873 2435-3345/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedour.app.name/our.app.main.timetable.NewRecurrentActivity/45000
```

but they don't seem to indicate errors with Firebase. There is absolutely no error reported by Firebase.

If the app is **installed cleanly** or if the **app data is reset**, then the app works properly.

We start to suspect that somehow Firebase is not properly handling its existing cache on the disk perhaps. Is there a way to force it to clear it and "start from scratch"?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you should contact [Firebase Support](http://firebase.google.com/support/)

Comment: I am also facing same issue , is this fixed?

Comment: @AnilKumarGN eventually we found out that the bug was in our code. We were using addListenerForSingleValueEvent instead of addValueEventListener.

Comment: I am using addValueEventListener only but still its not working . Do you know any other eason for this

Comment: In our case there was another bug caused by using firebase auth when only the api auth was required (the code was a bit messy). We removed firebase auth and fixed the listener and we were ok.